# Are there any replacement for Synaser Serial Communciation tool for Lazarus compiler?

Tags: linux, lazarus, serial-communication, apache-synapse

I am working with the latest Lazarus compiler and have worked with Synaser for serial communication with the previous version of Lazarus. It has worked flawlessly, but now with latest version of Lazarus Synaser code is not even compiling but raising all sorts of error.

So, my question is this. Are there any replacement for Synaser tool for Lazarus? if not, is there an update to Synaser tool?

FPC 2.6.2
Lazarus 1.0.8

Comment: Which version of Lazarus, which version of FPC, which version of synaser, what error ?

Comment: Lazarus 1.0.8 and FPC 2.6.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several Serial Communication (COM port) options available for Lazarus, but I would first suggest giving [Synaser](http://synapse.ararat.cz/) another try.

I'm currently using Lazarus 1.2.4 with Synaser from Synapse v40 and even latest trunk revision without any problems.

Alternative COM port implementations:

- [TComport port for Lazarus](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cportlaz/) (cportlaz)
- [Serial Communications Windows API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff802693.aspx) (CreateFile, ReadFile, SetCommMask, etc)
- more in [Hardware Access and Serial Communication for Lazarus](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Hardware_Access#Serial_Communication)

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own library, on both Windows and Linux the COM ports are just files that you read and write to.

To answer your question : NO as far as I know and I use Lazarus almost every day.

Try

http://www.pilotlogic.com/sitejoom/index.php/codetyphon/codetyphon-download

It has synaser bundeled in and lot's more

Comment: broken: `http://www.pilotlogic.com/sitejoom/index.php/codetyphon/codetyphon-download`